# What is the digital sum of $(99...9)^3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the digital sum of $(99...9)^3$ ? There are 12 nines in the expression.
My attempt
I have tried to write it as $(10^{12}-1)^3$ and tried to compute the digital sum of expanded expansion. But it is getting complicated and i am loosing track. Can any one help?